# Make Qt application not to quit when last window is closed

Tags: c++, qt

I've created a Qt application that acts mostly as a daemon, but occasionally shows a dialog.

Now, I know the default behavior is to close the application when the last window closes, but for my program, I need it to continue running. How do I change the behavior of my application?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can set the [QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) to `false`:

```cpp
QApplication qApp;
qApp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```