# Make application not quit even if Main window is closed

Tags: c++, qt

I want the application to run in background even if the main window is closed.

[I checked this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811141/make-qt-application-not-to-quit-when-last-window-is-closed) out and tried it but the application exits when I explicitly press exit button. I want the application to run in background even if I press exit explicitly.

I tried this

```
QApplication qApp;
qApp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

Comment: Have you tried a 2nd call of `qApp.exec()` after first? On Windows, it's not a problem at all to put code after `qApp.exec()` - we do this in our production code. About other platforms - I did not yet try this. Btw. `qApp` is an unlucky name. I once realized that there is a macro `qApp`. I fixed this with `#undef qApp` but got complaints from the (real) experts and ended up with something else... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff My application is being developed on Linux as of now. But do you suggest trying it anyways?

Comment: To try in a minimal example cannot hurt, can it? ;-) I remember roughly that I already answered something similar. If I only could find this answer... (Will keep on searching.)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It closed even after doing that:(

Comment: Found it. You could try this sample on your side: [SO: Qt exit application and show another window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237532/7478597) for a start. If I understood you right, you don't want a 2nd window. I'm not quite sure how to run `QGUIApplication` without a window. However, a detached child process might be an alternative solution. In another answer I showed that it can outlive the process where it was started from [SO: QProcess that will outlive the parent for updating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52226367/7478597)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's better for you to just try hiding main QWidget of your application using `setVisible(false)`

After that you'll need some way to open your main window back again(tray menu is first option I can come up with) with `setVisible(true)`

Comment: Yes. I used tray icon for getting back the application instance but I used close at the end of the click event function. I tried this and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of Daemon thread of multi-threading for the same. The thread continues to run even when the program is executed or exited.